# ZF2: Zend Framework 2 - how to render output without layout

Tags: zend-framework2

I know that I can use this

```
public function providerAction()
{
    $result = new ViewModel();
    $result->setTerminal(true);

   return $result;
}
```

But how do I pass variables to view? Before I did this

```
return array('items' => $items);
```

But now I have only one option either return array and then layout is there or return `$result` then variables are not in the view.

Comment: Another similar question with a more detailed reply.

See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870758/951920

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your example you could write like this:

```
public function providerAction()
{
    $result = new ViewModel();
    $result->setTerminal(true);
    $result->setVariables(array('items' => 'items'));
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent answer, would be good if you'd accepted it :)

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer works perfectly. I just want to add that instead of using `setVariables` you can also pass your variables directly when instantiating the `ViewModel` like this:

```
$result = new ViewModel(array('items' => $items));
```