# How to disable render view in zend framework 2?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2

I want to use some ajax, but I don't know how to use  function  as the same as setNoRender() in zend framework 2 to disable for render view.

How to disable rendering view in zend framework 2?

Comment: Another similar question with a more detailed reply.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870758/951920

Comment: Solution for ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21769601/260610

Answer (score 56, accepted):

- To disable your view :

  ```
  public function myactionAction()
  {
      // your code here ...
      return false;
  }
  ```

"return false" disables the view and not the layout! why? because the accepted types are:

- ViewModel
- array
- null

so "false" disable the view.

- To disable layout and view, return a response object:

  ```
  public function myactionAction()
  {
      // your code here ...
      return $this->response;
  }
  ```
- To disable layout:

  ```
  public function myactionAction()
  {
      // your code here ...
      $view = new ViewModel();
      $view->setTerminal(true);
      return $view;
  }
  ```

Comment: Its not $view->setTerminate(true);
Its $view->setTerminal(true);

Comment: Great answer. I updated the method call as Beniston rightly pointed out a typo.

Comment: Most of my action need to disable layout. Is there a way to set this from the view strategy, to avoid repeating code the above code?

Comment: This is a great answer but why does returning a Response object disable the layout and view? That's strange.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using JSON, then look at the view's `JsonStrategy` and return a `JsonModel` from you controller. See this [article](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/returning-json-from-a-zf2-controller-action/).

Alternatively, you can return an `Response` from your controller and the whole view layer is skipped:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setContent('foo');
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick notice. In Zend Framework 2.2 the $response->setBody('foo') is $response->setContent('foo');

Answer (score 9):

**Proper** and simple solution to do this

```
public function testAction()
{
    $data = array(
        'result' => true,
        'data' => array()
    );
    return $this->getResponse()->setContent(Json::encode($data));
}
```

Details: http://cmyker.blogspot.com/2012/11/zend-framework-2-ajax-return-json.html

Comment: For a REALLY proper solution, set the header first: public function testAction{ $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/json'); return $response->setContent(JSON::encode($data));}

Answer (score 3):

I found some answer.

Though `$this->layout()->getLayout()` returns the name/path of the newly selected layout... The layout does not change with any of the following commands...

within a controller

```
$this->getLocator()->get('view')->layout()->setLayout('layouts/ajax.phtml');
$this->getLocator()->get('view')->layout()->setLayout('ajax');
$this->getLocator()->get('view')->layout()->disableLayout();
```

within a view PHTML file

```
$this->layout()->setLayout('layouts/ajax.phtml');
$this->layout()->setLayout('ajax');
$this->layout()->disableLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

$view = new ViewModel();
 $view->setTerminate(true);

Comment: It's $view->setTerminal(true); actually. Maybe the API changed over time

Answer (score 0):

```
...
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;

public function myAction() {
    ...

    $view = new JsonModel($myArray);
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}
```