# Load only layout.phtml but not view in Zend Framework 3

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework3

Can we disable the view rendering for a zend appllication. But still load layout.html. 
I am building an angularjs+zend application.I have added my angularjs scripts in the layout.phtml but whenever i load a page it say 404 because i have not defined a html view for the route. To resolve this i have to define all route functions in the controllers. But i dont need this because i have my view in the front end/angularjs

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578869/7935051)!

Comment: Why your controller trying to send html view If you have a js frontend? i think you have to return jsonmodel not viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a `<?= $this->content ?>` row in your layout.phtml file. This is where the page view should take place.
If you delete this, it won't show anything.